# Can Application Insights automatically track queries to Cosmos Db with connection mode Direct?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights

Currently in Application Insights we are only seeing these operations between our .Net Core application and Cosmos db
[image]

but queries to actually query and insert data is not seen. We are using Direct connection mode as per the performance tips https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips.

Do we have to manually track these queries or can this be done automatically, like when using Sql Server.

Comment: Can you please share your App Insights query sample?  Also you might want to check in `dependencies` table, generally CosmosDB SQLs gets logged there. Or check this artical - https://chapsas.com/logging-your-applications-cosmosdb-activity-in-application-insights/ or https://www.jankowskimichal.pl/en/2019/03/logging-and-monitoring-cost-of-cosmosdb-queries-by-using-application-insights/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I turns out that queries to cosmos db using Direct connection mode are not automatically tracked, as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#automatically-tracked-dependencies

So all queries to Cosmos db must be tracked manually.